# How to make a code run for twice rows each as a group in a dataframe in R?

Tags: r, image, colors, range

I would like to proof if an image includes a certain color range. I have the following data, the code for color groups and the picture:

```
library(magick)
library(scatterplot3d)
library(colordistance)

image <- image_read("image.jpg")
colorpalette <- data.frame(group = c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4), 
A = c(0.25168911, 0.22669197,  0.22669197, 0.21293378, 0.21293378, 0.19612549, 0.19612549, 0.17940884), 
B = c(0.1477321049, 0.1738456673, 0.1738456673, 0.1149389567, 0.1149389567, 0.1365333333, 0.1365333333, 0.0737957272), 
C = c(0.0887786440, 0.1442915876, 0.1442915876, 0.0545024047, 0.0545024047, 0.1020078431, 0.1020078431, 0.0139303483))
                              
upper1 <- c(0.22669197, 0.1738456673, 0.1442915876)
lower1 <- c(0.21293378, 0.1149389567, 0.0545024047)
                              
group1 <- countColors("image.jpg", color.range = "rectangular", upper = upper1, lower = lower1, bg.lower = NULL, plotting = TRUE, target.color = "orange")
```

[image]

I would like to transfer this and run this code for all color groups (1-4) within the predefined colorpalette.
The url for the picture:
https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fdigitalsynopsis.com%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2016%2F05%2Fcinema-palettes-famous-movie-colors-star-wars-the-force-awakens.jpg&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fdigitalsynopsis.com%2Fdesign%2Fcinema-palettes-famous-movie-colors%2F&tbnid=x8RFFszidcs6-M&vet=12ahUKEwiY892Tj9f2AhUp1-AKHdjVBNsQMygAegQIARAd..i&docid=sZw2jvuqpGDZ2M&w=780&h=551&q=cinema-palettes-famous-movie-colors-star-wars-the-force-awakens.jpg&client=firefox-b-e&ved=2ahUKEwiY892Tj9f2AhUp1-AKHdjVBNsQMygAegQIARAd

Comment: What do you mean by "transfer this"?  In your example, the values of `upper1` and `lower1` appear to correspond to `group` values of `2` in your data frame.  Are you saying that, in your data frame, the first row for each group corresponds to the values you want for `upper1` and the second row to the values for `lower1`?

Comment: like make it run for each group without the need to change all the numbers myself. Yes exactly - that's it with upper and lower...

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused by your initial code as the online doc for `colordistance` suggests that `countColors` is not exported from the package.  However, here's a proof of concept example to show you the sort of thing you will need to do.

My plan is to use the `group_map` function from the tidyverse.  To do this, I need to reformat your `colorpalette` dataframe so that the input parameters to `countColors` (or any other function) are each contained in the columns of one row (or group) of the data frame.  Your format won't work because you have the values we need in the rows of each column.  So I need to `pivot` the dataframe.

```
library(tidyverse)

d <- colorpalette %>% 
  add_column(limit=rep(c("upper", "lower"), times=4)) %>% 
  nest(data=c(A, B, C)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from=limit, values_from=data)
d
# A tibble: 4 × 3
  group upper            lower           
  <dbl> <list>           <list>          
1     1 <tibble [1 × 3]> <tibble [1 × 3]>
2     2 <tibble [1 × 3]> <tibble [1 × 3]>
3     3 <tibble [1 × 3]> <tibble [1 × 3]>
4     4 <tibble [1 × 3]> <tibble [1 × 3]>
```

That looks a little odd, but the original data points are still there.  For example:

```
d$upper[1]
[[1]]
# A tibble: 1 × 3
      A     B      C
  <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
1 0.252 0.148 0.0888
```

As I mentioned, it seems that I can't run `countColors`.  So, as a demonstration, I'll simply calculate the Euclidean distances between the 3-dimensional points defined by each row of `upper` and `lower`

```
d %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  group_map(
    function(.x, .y) {
      y <- .x %>% unnest(
                    c(upper, lower), 
                    names_repair=function(x) {
                      c("group", "A1", "B1", "C1", "A2", "B2", "C2") 
                    } 
                  )
      list(delta=(y$A1 - y$A2)^2 + (y$B1 - y$B2)^2 + (y$C1 - y$C2)^2)
    }
  ) %>% 
  bind_rows()
# A tibble: 4 × 1
    delta
    <dbl>
1 0.00439
2 0.0117 
3 0.00301
4 0.0120
```

I'm **not** suggesting that's a sensible way of calculating Euclidean distances.  I'm just illustrating a technique.

That suggests you might get what you want with something like

```
colorpalette %>% 
  add_column(limit=rep(c("upper", "lower"), times=4)) %>% 
  nest(data=c(A, B, C)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from=limit, values_from=data) %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  group_map(
    function(.x, .y) {
      countColors(
        "image.jpg", 
        color.range = "rectangular", 
        upper = .x$upper, 
        lower = .x$lower, 
        bg.lower = NULL, 
        plotting = TRUE, 
        target.color = "orange"
      )
    }
  )
```

But I can't be sure because I can't test the code.

Comment: Unfortunately the code is not running. "Error in countColors("image.jpg", : 
Lower must be a vector with length a multiple of 3
or a matrix of lower bounds"

Comment: I just want to build groups starting with group 1 (upper1, lower1), then group2 (upper2, lower2), group3 (upper3, lower3) and group4 (upper4, lower4) and use the code for each group. Maybe a list would help?